# AngularJS is not parsing our JSON array property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, parsing

Our GET request returns the following response:

```
{
    "access_token": "pi7ID4bsZIC9yN ... 76gnblw",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 1209599,
    "userName": "super0",
    "userRoles": "["member", "admin"]",
    ".issued": "Tue, 04 Feb 2014 05:07:51 GMT",
    ".expires": "Tue, 18 Feb 2014 05:07:51 GMT"
}
```

The problem is that AngularJS parses it into the following object.

```
data: Object
    .expires: "Tue, 18 Feb 2014 05:07:51 GMT"
    .issued: "Tue, 04 Feb 2014 05:07:51 GMT"
    access_token: "pi7ID4bsZIC9yN ... 76gnblw"
    expires_in: 1209599
    token_type: "bearer"
    userName: "super0"
    userRoles: "["member", "admin"]"
    __proto__: Object
```

We need "userRoles" to parse into a JavaScript array not a string as shown. How can we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not valid JSON. The array should not be quoted.

It should look like this instead:

```
{
    "access_token": "pi7ID4bsZIC9yN ... 76gnblw",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 1209599,
    "userName": "super0",
    "userRoles": ["member", "admin"],
    ".issued": "Tue, 04 Feb 2014 05:07:51 GMT",
    ".expires": "Tue, 18 Feb 2014 05:07:51 GMT"
}
```

Comment: Aha. That makes sense. The problem then is that I am unable to return an unquoted array, because C# creates the JSON GET response from a Dictionary<string,string>. The JSON property value must be a string, and I don't know how to include square brackets outside the quotes `data.Add("userRoles", "['admin', 'member']");`

Comment: Can you make that a `Dictionary<string, object>` instead, so the value for the userRoles key can be an Array (or IEnumerable of some sort)? Then, it should serialize correctly.

Comment: I could try that but am hesitant. ASP.NET Identity's AuthenticationProperties() constructor takes a Dictionary<string,string>. Implementing our own AuthenticationProperties class might do the trick. That's going to require some work, though. Hmm.

Comment: I will probably just pass the userRoles as CSV instead.